# Need help in the longtable with the figure

Tags: longtable

Can u please help me in this table. The problem in this table that is not move to the next page in a proper way and kindly mention the size of the figure as well as the place of the figure.

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
\caption{Bacteria isolates on different media}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\toprule
\textbf{Sr.No} &
  \textbf{Reference Code} &
  \textbf{Sample Location} &
  \textbf{Colony Color} &
  \textbf{Colony Morphology} &
  \textbf{Pigmentation} &
  \textbf{Media} &
  \textbf{Predicted Name Of Strain} &
  \textbf{Figures} \\* \midrule
\endhead
%
1 &
  EMB(P)1 &
  Islamabad &
  Green sheen &
  Circular &
  Green Sheen &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Eosin methylene\\    \\ blue agar\end{tabular} &
  \textit{\textbf{E.coil}} &
   \\* \midrule
2 &
  MSA(P)1 &
  Islamabad &
  Yellow &
  Punctiform &
  Yellow &
  Mannitol salt agar &
  \textit{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Staphylococcus\\    \\ Epidermidis\end{tabular}}} &
   \\* \midrule
3  & MACC(P)1 & Islamabad & Off white       & Circular  & Off white       & MacConkey agar     & \textit{\textbf{Salmonella}}              &  \\* \midrule
4  & MSA(P)2  & Islamabad & White           & Circular  & White           & Mannitol salt agar & \textit{\textbf{Staphylococcus   aureus}} &  \\* \midrule
5 &
  B.A(P)1 &
  Islamabad &
  White &
  Smooth &
  White &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Blood \\    \\ Agar\end{tabular} &
  \textit{\textbf{Pseudomonas   aeruginosa}} &
   \\* \midrule
6  & B.A(P)2  & Islamabad & White           & Circular  & White           & Blood agar         & \textit{\textbf{Lactobacilli}}            &  \\* \midrule
7  & MACC(P)2 & Islamabad & Pink            & Circular  & Pink            & MacConkey agar     & \textit{\textbf{Klebsiella}}              &  \\* \midrule
8  & MACC(P)3 & Islamabad & Purple          & Irregular & Purple          & MacConkey agar     & \textit{\textbf{pseudomonas}}             &  \\* \midrule
9  & MSA(P)3  & Islamabad & Crystal White   & spherical & Crystal White   & Mannitol salt agar & \textit{\textbf{Salmonella}}              &  \\* \midrule
10 & B.A(P)3  & Islamabad & White           & Puntiform & White           & Blood agar         & \textit{\textbf{Staphylococcus}}          &  \\* \midrule
11 & MACC(P)4 & Islamabad & Orange to amber & Circular  & Orange to amber & MacConkey agar     & \textit{\textbf{Shigella}}                &  \\* \midrule
12 & MSA(P)4  & Islamabad & Yellow          & Circular  & Yellow          & Mannitol salt agar & \textit{\textbf{S. aureus}}               &  \\* \midrule
13 & MACC(P)5 & Islamabad & Pink to purple  & Circular  & Pink to purple  & MacConkey          & \textit{\textbf{Klebisella}}              &  \\* \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: The problem is in width of the table.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ and how tall and wide the text block is. (Or, if it's easier to do, please tell us about the paper size and the margin widths.)

Comment: Combining vertical lines with horizontal lines from the `booktabs` package is somewhat against the design choice of `booktabs` as its horizontal lines are meant to be used without vertical lines.

Comment: Which figure are you referring to with "size and place of the figure"?

Comment: Does the code contain the whole table or will you add mor rows later on? As it currently is, your table should fit onto a single page, at least height-wise. So I don't really see the need for `longtable` here.

Comment: The figure is saved in the form of the image and in the folder of gfx where the main file of the latex is save.

Comment: I did not add more row that is similar that u have send me. I just add the figure in that. Can u made the landscape long table with this data.

Comment: To be honest, I can't see where/how you inlcude a figure here. I only see a table column with a column header "Figure". Do you want to insert an image in every cell of this column? (Using the `\includegraphics` command)?

Comment: Since your table is quite wide you will need to find some ways to save space. One of these would be removing column. Do you really need the "Location"  column?  All entries are the same, so you could just place this information in the caption of the table and save some space. Also, the information in the "Colony color"  and "Pigmentation"  column is basically identical. Do you really need both columns?

Comment: yes i need that because these are my result of the thesis.

Comment: Wait I will send u my word document image that i made that table.

Comment: The "result of the thesis" means that you need to include the information in the thesis.  Nothing says you have to include the information in the table.  It would help make the table smaller to adjust the caption to include "all samples came from Islamabad".

Comment: Any news? You receive three answers, does any of them fulfil your expectations?, if, please upvote this answer(s) and the best suited one accept (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of this answer).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a standard page size and margins no wider than 2.5cm, the table should fit on a page as long as you allow line-breaking in the cells. In the following, this is done by employing a `tabularx` column. I would also recommend getting rid of all vertical bars (they're not needed; in fact, they're a distraction) and replacing most instances of `\midrule` with `\addlinespace`. I would also get rid of all **bold-facing** in order to avoid creating a somewhat vulgar and noisy "look".

I will confess that I do not understand what you intend to do with the 'Figures' column.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % choose a suitable document class
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{MACC(P)5} % width of column 2
\hyphenation{sal-mo-nel-la pseudo-monas mac-con-key aeru-gi-nosa epi-der-mi-dis}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.5pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{Bacteria isolates on different media\strut}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l p{\mylen} *{6}{L} l @{}}
\toprule
  Sr.No &
  Reference Code & Sample Location & Colony Color & Colony Morphology & 
  Pigmentation & Media & Predicted Name of Strain & Figures \\ 
\midrule
1  & EMB(P)1  & Islamabad & Green sheen     & Circular  & Green Sheen     & Eosin methylene blue agar & \textit{E. coli}           &  \\ \addlinespace
2  & MSA(P)1  & Islamabad & Yellow          & Punctiform& Yellow          & Mannitol salt agar & \textit{Staphylococcus Epidermidis}&\\ \addlinespace
3  & MACC(P)1 & Islamabad & Off white       & Circular  & Off white       & MacConkey agar     & \textit{Salmonella}              &  \\ \addlinespace
4  & MSA(P)2  & Islamabad & White           & Circular  & White           & Mannitol salt agar & \textit{Staphylococcus aureus}   &  \\ \addlinespace
5  & B.A(P)1  & Islamabad & White           & Smooth    & White           & Blood Agar         & \textit{Pseudomonas aeruginosa}  &  \\ \addlinespace
6  & B.A(P)2  & Islamabad & White           & Circular  & White           & Blood agar         & \textit{Lactobacilli}            &  \\ \addlinespace
7  & MACC(P)2 & Islamabad & Pink            & Circular  & Pink            & MacConkey agar     & \textit{Klebsiella}              &  \\ \addlinespace
8  & MACC(P)3 & Islamabad & Purple          & Irregular & Purple          & MacConkey agar     & \textit{pseudomonas}             &  \\ \addlinespace
9  & MSA(P)3  & Islamabad & Crystal White   & spherical & Crystal White   & Mannitol salt agar & \textit{Salmonella}              &  \\ \addlinespace
10 & B.A(P)3  & Islamabad & White           & Punctiform& White           & Blood agar         & \textit{Staphylococcus}          &  \\ \addlinespace
11 & MACC(P)4 & Islamabad & Orange to amber & Circular  & Orange to amber & MacConkey agar     & \textit{Shigella}                &  \\ \addlinespace
12 & MSA(P)4  & Islamabad & Yellow          & Circular  & Yellow          & Mannitol salt agar & \textit{S. aureus}               &  \\ \addlinespace
13 & MACC(P)5 & Islamabad & Pink to purple  & Circular  & Pink to purple  & MacConkey          & \textit{Klebisella}              &  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am still not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I guess the following is at least somewhat close to the output you're looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}cccccc>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\widthof{MacConkey}}>{\itshape\bfseries}Xc@{}}
\caption{Bacteria isolates on different media}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\toprule
\thead{Sr.\\No} &
  \thead{Reference\\ Code} &
  \thead{Sample\\ Location} &
  \thead{Colony\\ Color} &
  \thead{Colony\\ Morphology} &
  \thead{Pigmen-\\tation} &
  \thead{Media} &
  \upshape\thead{Predicted\\ Name Of Strain} &
  \thead{Figures} \\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Bacteria isolates on different media - continued from previous page}\\
\toprule
\thead{Sr.\\No} &
  \thead{Reference\\ Code} &
  \thead{Sample\\ Location} &
  \thead{Colony\\ Color} &
  \thead{Colony\\ Morphology} &
  \thead{Pigmen-\\tation} &
  \thead{Media} &
  \upshape\thead{Predicted Name\\ Of Strain} &
  \thead{Figures} \\ \midrule
\endhead
%
1 &
  EMB(P)1 &
  Islamabad &
  \makecell[t]{Green\\ sheen} &
  Circular &
  \makecell[t]{Green\\ sheen} &
  \makecell[t]{Eosin\\ methylene\\blue agar} &
  E.coil & \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}
   \\ \midrule
2 &
  MSA(P)1 &   Islamabad &   Yellow &   Punctiform &   Yellow &   Mannitol salt agar &  Staphylococcus Epidermidis &\includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}
   \\ \midrule
3  & MACC(P)1 & Islamabad & \makecell[t]{Off\\ white}       & Circular  & \makecell[t]{Off\\ white}       & MacConkey agar     & Salmonella              & \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
4  & MSA(P)2  & Islamabad & White           & Circular  & White           & Mannitol salt agar & Staphylococcus   aureus &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
5 &
  B.A(P)1 &
  Islamabad &
  White &
  Smooth &
  White &
  Blood Agar &
  Pseudomonas   aeruginosa & \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}
   \\ \midrule
6  & B.A(P)2  & Islamabad & White           & Circular  & White           & Blood agar         & Lactobacilli            &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
7  & MACC(P)2 & Islamabad & Pink            & Circular  & Pink            & MacConkey agar     & Klebsiella              &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
8  & MACC(P)3 & Islamabad & Purple          & Irregular & Purple          & MacConkey agar     & pseudomonas            &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
9  & MSA(P)3  & Islamabad & \makecell[t]{Crystal\\ White}   & spherical & \makecell[t]{Crystal\\ White}   & Mannitol salt agar & Salmonella              &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
10 & B.A(P)3  & Islamabad & White           & Puntiform & White           & Blood agar         & Staphylococcus          &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
11 & MACC(P)4 & Islamabad & \makecell[t]{Orange to\\ amber} & Circular  & \makecell[t]{Orange to\\ amber} & MacConkey agar     & Shigella                &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a} \\ \midrule
12 & MSA(P)4  & Islamabad & Yellow          & Circular  & Yellow          & Mannitol salt agar & S. aureus               &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
13 & MACC(P)5 & Islamabad & \makecell[t]{Pink to\\ purple}  & Circular  & \makecell[t]{Pink to\\ purple}  & MacConkey          & Klebisell              &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=t]{example-image-a}\\ \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is an updated version of the code taking into account the information provided in [problem in the table when I add the figures in colunm of the table that is my result](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/582310/134144)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[top=1.5in,
            bottom=1.19in,inner=1.5in,outer=1in, 
            headheight=0.3in,headsep=0.2in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}cccccc>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\widthof{MacConkey}}>{\itshape\bfseries}Xc@{}}
\caption{Bacteria isolates on different media}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\toprule
\thead{Sr.\\No} &
  \thead{Reference\\ Code} &
  \thead{Sample\\ Location} &
  \thead{Colony\\ Color} &
  \thead{Colony\\ Morphology} &
  \thead{Pigmen-\\tation} &
  \thead{Media} &
  \upshape\thead{Predicted\\ Name Of Strain} &
  \thead{Figures} \\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Bacteria isolates on different media - continued from previous page}\\
\toprule
\thead{Sr.\\No} &
  \thead{Reference\\ Code} &
  \thead{Sample\\ Location} &
  \thead{Colony\\ Color} &
  \thead{Colony\\ Morphology} &
  \thead{Pigmen-\\tation} &
  \thead{Media} &
  \upshape\thead{Predicted Name\\ Of Strain} &
  \thead{Figures} \\ \midrule
\endhead
%
1 &
  EMB(P)1 &
  Islamabad &
  Green sheen &
  Circular &
  Green sheen &
  Eosin methylene blue agar &
  E.coil & \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}
   \\ \midrule
2 &
  MSA(P)1 &   Islamabad &   Yellow &   Punctiform &   Yellow &   Mannitol salt agar &  Staphylococcus Epidermidis &\includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}
   \\ \midrule
3  & MACC(P)1 & Islamabad & Off white       & Circular  & Off white       & MacConkey agar     & Salmonella              & \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
4  & MSA(P)2  & Islamabad & White           & Circular  & White           & Mannitol salt agar & Staphylococcus   aureus &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
5 &
  B.A(P)1 &
  Islamabad &
  White &
  Smooth &
  White &
  Blood Agar &
  Pseudomonas   aeruginosa & \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}
   \\ \midrule
6  & B.A(P)2  & Islamabad & White           & Circular  & White           & Blood agar         & Lactobacilli            &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
7  & MACC(P)2 & Islamabad & Pink            & Circular  & Pink            & MacConkey agar     & Klebsiella              &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
8  & MACC(P)3 & Islamabad & Purple          & Irregular & Purple          & MacConkey agar     & pseudomonas            &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
9  & MSA(P)3  & Islamabad & Crystal White   & spherical & Crystal White   & Mannitol salt agar & Salmonella              &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
10 & B.A(P)3  & Islamabad & White           & Puntiform & White           & Blood agar         & Staphylococcus          &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
11 & MACC(P)4 & Islamabad & Orange to amber & Circular  & Orange to amber & MacConkey agar     & Shigella                &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a} \\ \midrule
12 & MSA(P)4  & Islamabad & Yellow          & Circular  & Yellow          & Mannitol salt agar & S. aureus               &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}\\ \midrule
13 & MACC(P)5 & Islamabad & Pink to purple  & Circular  & Pink to purple  & MacConkey          & Klebisell              &  \includegraphics[width=3cm, valign=c]{example-image-a}\\ \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Question is not entirely clear, so some suggestion may miss the your problem. I suggest to use:

- landscape oriented pages for table (since it is quite wide with using normal font size)
- `xltabular` table (similar as @leandriis in his answer),
- for all columns except the first and last use `C` columns derived from `X` columns
- remove all `\makcell{...}` commands from table body
- for including images to use `\adjustimage{}{...}`, for which declare common settings for image size, position and margins

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash%
                     \hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % it also load graphicx

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
    \adjustboxset{width=24mm, valign=t, margin=0pt 2pt 0pt 2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} c
                                *{3}{L{0.85}} 
                                     L{1.05}
                                *{2}{L{0.9}}
                                >{\itshape\bfseries}L{1.6} 
                                  c @{}}
\caption{Bacteria isolates on different media}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
    \toprule
\thead{Sr.\\No} 
    &   \thead{Reference\\ Code} 
        &   \thead{Sample\\ Location} 
            & \thead{Colony\\ Color} 
                &   \thead{Colony\\ Morphology} 
                    &   \thead{Pigmen-\\tation} 
                        &   \thead{Media} 
                            & \upshape\thead{Predicted\\ Name Of Strain} 
                                &   \thead{Figures}         \\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{Bacteria isolates on different media (cont).}    \\
    \toprule
\thead{Sr.\\No}
    &   \thead{Reference\\ Code}
        &   \thead{Sample\\ Location}
            & \thead{Colony\\ Color}
                &   \thead{Colony\\ Morphology}
                    &   \thead{Pigmen-\\tation}
                        &   \thead{Media}
                            & \upshape\thead{Predicted\\ Name Of Strain}
                                &   \thead{Figures}     \\ \midrule
\endhead
    \multicolumn{9}{r}{\footnotesize\emph{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
%%%% table body
1   &   EMB(P)1 
        &   Islamabad 
                &   Green sheen
                    &   Circular
                        &   Green sheen
                            &   Eosin methylene blue agar
                                &   E.coil
                                    &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} \\ \midrule
2   &   MSA(P)1 
        &   Islamabad 
            &   Yellow
                &   Punctiform
                    &   Yellow
                        &   Mannitol salt agar
                            &   Staphylococcus Epidermidis
                                &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}   \\ \midrule
3   &   MACC(P)1    
        &   Islamabad 
            &   Off white
                &   Circular  
                    &   Off white
                        &   MacConkey agar 
                            &   Salmonella
                                &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}     \\ \midrule
4   &   MSA(P)2  
        &   Islamabad & White           
            &   Circular  
                & White
                    &   Mannitol salt agar
                        &   Staphylococcus aureus 
                            &  \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}          \\ \midrule
5   & B.A(P)1 
    &   Islamabad 
        &   White 
            &   Smooth 
                &   White 
                    &   Blood Agar 
                        &   Pseudomonas aeruginosa 
                            &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}         \\ \midrule
6   &   B.A(P)2 
        &   Islamabad 
            &   White
                &   Circular
                    &   White           
                        &   Blood agar         
                            &   Lactobacilli
                                &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}     \\ \midrule
7   &   MACC(P)2 
        &   Islamabad 
            &   Pink            
                &   Circular  
                    &   Pink            
                        &   MacConkey agar     
                            &   Klebsiella              
                                &  \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}      \\ \midrule
8   &   MACC(P)3 
        &   Islamabad 
            &   Purple          
                &   Irregular 
                    &   Purple          
                        &   MacConkey agar     
                            &   Pseudomonas            
                                &  \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}      \\ \midrule
9   &   MSA(P)3  
        &   Islamabad 
            &   Crystal White
                &   spherical 
                    &   Crystal White
                        &   Mannitol salt agar 
                            &   Salmonella              
                                    &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} \\ \midrule
10  &   B.A(P)3  
        &   Islamabad 
            &   White           
                &   Puntiform 
                    &   White           
                        &   Blood agar         
                            &   Staphylococcus         
                                &  \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}      \\ \midrule
11  &   MACC(P)4 
        &   Islamabad 
            &   Orange to amber
                &   Circular  
                    &   Orange to amber
                        &   MacConkey agar     
                            &   Shigella                
                                &  \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}      \\ \midrule
12  &   MSA(P)4  
        &   Islamabad 
            &   Yellow
                &   Circular  
                    &   Yellow
                        &   Mannitol salt agar 
                            &   S. aureus               
                                &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}     \\ \midrule
13  &   MACC(P)5 
        &   Islamabad 
            &   Pink to purple
                &   Circular  
                    &   Pink to purple
                        &   MacConkey
                            &   Klebisell
                                &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}     \\ \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the table are nicely and correctly breaked between the pages.

**Addendum:**
If you like to have table in portrait page format, then you need to reduce:

- table body font size, for example to `\footnotesize`
- column headers font size, for example to `\scriptsize`
- `\tabcolsep` size, for example to 3pt
- reduce image size, for example to width=18mm

After this reductions table can fit on one page (assuming that you provide complete contet of table) and consequently it can be inserted into float `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1.5in,  % consider your next (unclear) question
            bottom=1.19in,inner=1.5in,outer=1in,
            headheight=0.3in,headsep=0.2in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\scriptsize\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash%
                     \hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % it also load graphicx

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[p]
\caption{Bacteria isolates on different media}
\label{tab:my-table}
    \footnotesize
    \adjustboxset{width=18mm, valign=t, margin=0pt 2pt 0pt 2pt}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}c
                                L{1}
                           *{2}{L{0.9}}
                                L{1.1}
                                L{0.8}
                                L{0.9}
            >{\itshape\bfseries}L{1.4}
                                c @{}}
    \toprule
\thead{Sr.\\No}
    &   \thead{Reference\\ Code}
        &   \thead{Sample\\ Location}
            & \thead{Colony\\ Color}
                &   \thead{Colony\\ Morphology}
                    &   \thead{Pigmen-\\tation}
                        &   \thead{Media}
                            & \upshape\thead{Predicted\\ Name Of Strain}
                                &   \thead{Figures}         \\ \midrule
%%%% table body
1   &   EMB(P)1
        &   Islamabad
                &   Green sheen
                    &   Circular
                        &   Green sheen
                            &   Eosin methylene blue agar
                                &   E.coil
                                    &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} \\ \midrule
2   &   MSA(P)1
        &   Islamabad
            &   Yellow
                &   Punctiform
                    &   Yellow
                        &   Mannitol salt agar
                            &   Staphylococcus Epidermidis
                                &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}   \\ \midrule
3   &   MACC(P)1
        &   Islamabad
            &   Off white
                &   Circular
                    &   Off white
                        &   MacConkey agar
                            &   Salmonella
                                &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}     \\ \midrule
4   &   MSA(P)2
        &   Islamabad & White
            &   Circular
                & White
                    &   Mannitol salt agar
                        &   Staphylococcus aureus
                            &  \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}          \\ \midrule
5   & B.A(P)1
    &   Islamabad
        &   White
            &   Smooth
                &   White
                    &   Blood Agar
                        &   Pseudomonas aeruginosa
                            &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}         \\ \midrule
6   &   B.A(P)2
        &   Islamabad
            &   White
                &   Circular
                    &   White
                        &   Blood agar
                            &   Lactobacilli
                                &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}     \\ \midrule
7   &   MACC(P)2
        &   Islamabad
            &   Pink
                &   Circular
                    &   Pink
                        &   MacConkey agar
                            &   Klebsiella
                                &  \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}      \\ \midrule
8   &   MACC(P)3
        &   Islamabad
            &   Purple
                &   Irregular
                    &   Purple
                        &   MacConkey agar
                            &   Pseudomonas
                                &  \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}      \\ \midrule
9   &   MSA(P)3
        &   Islamabad
            &   Crystal White
                &   spherical
                    &   Crystal White
                        &   Mannitol salt agar
                            &   Salmonella
                                    &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck} \\ \midrule
10  &   B.A(P)3
        &   Islamabad
            &   White
                &   Puntiform
                    &   White
                        &   Blood agar
                            &   Staphylococcus
                                &  \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}      \\ \midrule
11  &   MACC(P)4
        &   Islamabad
            &   Orange to amber
                &   Circular
                    &   Orange to amber
                        &   MacConkey agar
                            &   Shigella
                                &  \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}      \\ \midrule
12  &   MSA(P)4
        &   Islamabad
            &   Yellow
                &   Circular
                    &   Yellow
                        &   Mannitol salt agar
                            &   S. aureus
                                &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}     \\ \midrule
13  &   MACC(P)5
        &   Islamabad
            &   Pink to purple
                &   Circular
                    &   Pink to purple
                        &   MacConkey
                            &   Klebisell
                                &   \adjustimage{}{example-image-duck}     \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Weakness of this solution is size of images. To have larger images, you need to search for some other solution (enabling that table can spil out of outer text border, for example) or stick with the first solution, which use landscape oriented table.