# That is still not working the problem is their in long table in the width the figure is not shown

Tags: longtable

this is the code

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
    \caption{Bacteria isolates on different media}
    \label{tab:my-table}\\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Sr.No} &
    \textbf{Reference Code} &
    \textbf{Sample Location} &
    \textbf{Colony Color} &
    \textbf{Colony Morphology} &
    \textbf{Pigmentation} &
    \textbf{Media} &
    \textbf{Predicted Name Of Strain} &
    \textbf{Figures} \\* \midrule
    \endhead
    %
    1 &
    EMB(P)1 &
    Islamabad &
    Green sheen &
    Circular &
    Green Sheen &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Eosin methylene\\    \\ blue agar\end{tabular} &
    \textit{\textbf{E.coil}} &\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{e.coil.png}*
    \\* \midrule
    2 &
    MSA(P)1 &
    Islamabad &
    Yellow &
    Punctiform &
    Yellow &
    Mannitol salt agar &
    \textit{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Staphylococcus\\    \\ Epidermidis\end{tabular}}} &
    \\* \midrule
    3  & MACC(P)1 & Islamabad & Off white       & Circular  & Off white       & MacConkey agar     & \textit{\textbf{Salmonella}}              &  \\* \midrule
    4  & MSA(P)2  & Islamabad & White           & Circular  & White           & Mannitol salt agar & \textit{\textbf{Staphylococcus   aureus}} &  \\* \midrule
    5 &
    B.A(P)1 &
    Islamabad &
    White &
    Smooth &
    White &
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Blood \\    \\ Agar\end{tabular} &
    \textit{\textbf{Pseudomonas   aeruginosa}} &
    \\* \midrule
    6  & B.A(P)2  & Islamabad & White           & Circular  & White           & Blood agar         & \textit{\textbf{Lactobacilli}}            &  \\* \midrule
    7  & MACC(P)2 & Islamabad & Pink            & Circular  & Pink            & MacConkey agar     & \textit{\textbf{Klebsiella}}              &  \\* \midrule
    8  & MACC(P)3 & Islamabad & Purple          & Irregular & Purple          & MacConkey agar     & \textit{\textbf{pseudomonas}}             &  \\* \midrule
    9  & MSA(P)3  & Islamabad & Crystal White   & spherical & Crystal White   & Mannitol salt agar & \textit{\textbf{Salmonella}}              &  \\* \midrule
    10 & B.A(P)3  & Islamabad & White           & Puntiform & White           & Blood agar         & \textit{\textbf{Staphylococcus}}          &  \\* \midrule
    11 & MACC(P)4 & Islamabad & Orange to amber & Circular  & Orange to amber & MacConkey agar     & \textit{\textbf{Shigella}}                &  \\* \midrule
    12 & MSA(P)4  & Islamabad & Yellow          & Circular  & Yellow          & Mannitol salt agar & \textit{\textbf{S. aureus}}               &  \\* \midrule
    13 & MACC(P)5 & Islamabad & Pink to purple  & Circular  & Pink to purple  & MacConkey          & \textit{\textbf{Klebisella}}              &  \\* \bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference to your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/582240/134144)?

Comment: this appears to be identical to the previous question and still does not provide an example that shows the problem. Your table is presumably wider than your page but you have given no information  about that.