# problem in the table when I add the figures in column of the table that is my result

Tags: tables

This is my original table which I want to make in latex.

```
\usepackage[top=1.5in,
            bottom=1.19in,inner=1.5in,outer=1in, 
            \headheight=0.3in,headsep=0.2in]{geometry}
```

that is my mirgan which r given by the university.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the problem? Providing a code row about your document layout is not sufficient information about your problem. You already ask similar question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582240/need-help-in-the-longtable-with-the-figure on which you receive three good answers. Does not any of them solve your problem?